# Hibernate issue java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String Using JDK 1.7

Tags: java, hibernate, java-7, java-6

I am facing issue with Hibernate.

Using Hibernate 3.2.6 and JDK 1.7.0_21

**Is this issue coming due to JDK compatibility with Hibernate version?**

This issue is random. I still unable to find steps to reproduce.

```
2014-07-14 06:09:10,661 [DEBUG] EventExpenseAreaService.getEventSummary:654 - Revenue Value (Hari) --> 1166.15
2014-07-14 06:09:18,665 [ERROR] EventSetupService.getEventById:1451 - java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.hibernate.type.StringType.toString(StringType.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeToString(NullableType.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2002)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2376)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2312)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2612)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at com.sibisoft.northstar.events.service.EventSetupService.getEventById(EventSetupService.java:1441)
    at com.sibisoft.northstar.events.struts.EventAction.load(EventAction.java:1037)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Code getEventById

```
public EventDTO getEventById(Integer eventId,boolean logActivity, Session session)throws Exception {

    EventDTO event = null;
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {

        if (session == null) {
            session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
            if(logActivity){
                transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            }
        }

        event = (EventDTO) super.getByPrimaryKey(EventDTO.class, eventId,session);


        if(transaction!=null){
            transaction.commit();
        }

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        if(transaction!=null){
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        throw e;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        if(transaction!=null){
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        throw e;
    }

    return event;

}
```

Method : getByPrimaryKey

```
protected BaseEventDTO getByPrimaryKey(Class clazz, Integer pk,Session session) throws Exception{

    BaseEventDTO dto = null;
    Transaction tx = null;

    try {

        if (session == null)  {
            session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
        }
        dto = (BaseEventDTO) session.get(clazz, pk);
        return dto;

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        LOGGER.error(e);
        if (tx !=null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code of : com.sibisoft.northstar.events.service.EventSetupService.getEventById()

Comment: See code, I have add code in my question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JDK 7 have changed `Class.getDeclaredMethods()` so the order is not guaranteed. [[click here]](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7023180)

You might have a property in Object mapping that have getter method `String getProperty()` as well as `Boolean isPropery()` that is causing problem intermittently.

Hibernate 3 `BasicPropertyAccessor.getterMethod(...)` some time finds `getProperty()` and some time `isProperty()` due to unspecified ordering in JDK 7 by `getDeclaredMethods()`. which confuses hibernate and it invokes Boolean Type method for String type property.

You need to rename one method to get expected results.

Similar question on Hibernate Forum: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2474641